# Using azure curl command with dollar

Tags: shell, azure, curl

Hi I am using the curl command to fetch azure activity log 
`curl -X GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2019-03-18T20:00:00Z' and eventTimestamp le '2019-03-23T20:00:00Z' and resourceGroupName eq 'xxxx'`

its giving error 
`bash: =eventTimestamp: command not found`
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

`&$` are shell special characters. `&` puts the preceding command in the background. `$filter` evaluates the variable named filter, which is obviously empty. So you're left with the second command `=eventTimestamp` with some parameters and bash complains.
Generally quote your url in `''`. But it gets more complicated because you have single quotes in the url. If you type this in you need to close the quote before any literal `'` and use `\'` for every `'` then open the quote again.

```
curl -X GET 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '\''2019-03-18T20:00:00Z'\'' and eventTimestamp le '\''2019-03-23T20:00:00Z'\'' and resourceGroupName eq '\''xxxx'\''
```

You can bypass this problem by typing urls like this in a file an read its content into a shell variable like this:

```
url=$(cat url_file)
```

or in the form of a here document:

```
url=$(cat <<'EOF'
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&$filter=eventTimestamp ge '2019-03-18T20:00:00Z' and eventTimestamp le '2019-03-23T20:00:00Z' and resourceGroupName eq 'xxxx'
EOF
)
```

and then do:

```
curl -X GET "$url"
```

Url encoding special characters would also work.

In case you need it you can use this shell function to quotify strings containing single quotes:

```
quotifySingle() {
    #does the same as
    #printf %s\\n "$(printf %s "$1" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g")"
    local input="$1"
    local tmp=''

    while [ ${#input} -gt 0 ]
    do
      tmp=${input#?}
      case ${input} in
        \'*)   printf \'\\\'\'      ;;
          *)   printf %s "${input%"${tmp}"}"  ;;
      esac
      input=${tmp}
    done

}
```